# Why "OnActionExecuting" is used instead of "OnActionExected" when minifying HTML in MVC using ActionFilters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement HTML minification by referring to this article: https://arranmaclean.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/minify-html-with-net-mvc-actionfilter/

```
public class WhitespaceFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        response.Filter = new WhiteSpaceFilter(response.Filter, s =>
        {
            s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ");
            s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\n\s*", "\n");
            s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\>\s*\<\s*", "><");
            s = Regex.Replace(s, @"<!--(.*?)-->", "");   //Remove comments

            // single-line doctype must be preserved 
            var firstEndBracketPosition = s.IndexOf(">");
            if (firstEndBracketPosition >= 0)
            {
                s = s.Remove(firstEndBracketPosition, 1);
                s = s.Insert(firstEndBracketPosition, ">");
            }
            return s;
        });

    }
}
```

Why is the author using `OnActionExecuting` instead of `OnActionExected`? 
We know `OnActionExecuting` executes before the action and `OnActionExected` executes after the action. If I changed it to `OnActionExected` then would that work?

Comment: I haven't looked at the lifecycle but I would guess because maybe after the action has executed the response has already been sent and it's too late to change it? TBH though why not just try it and see? It'd be quite a quick change to make, probably as quick as asking an SO question...

Comment: i asked this just for knowledge purpose that when OnActionExected fire then view is sent to client? we can not change the view data from OnActionExected ?

Comment: Like I said, that's my guess. Seriously wouldn't it take you less time to experiment with it yourself than waiting for answers on SO?

Comment: can you give any idea like how to test that we can get control over html from  OnActionExected function.

Comment: How about making an onActionExecuted filter and see what parameters are available to you? And read the documentation? If you can't get hold of the response HTML as part of the values passed into the filter then perhaps that gives you your answer... I'm surprised someone with your rep level has not got a bit more more initiative to be able to find things out and test them. I just commented as a quick guess, I don't have time to look into it in detail right now, but your profile suggests you have more than enough experience and knowledge to do so competently.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to use a filter in MVC. The purpose of a filter is to execute logic to *filter out certain requests* from executing a specific action. The filter *does not actually execute* the action (or at least it isn't supposed to). Instead, it sets a handler (usually to `filterContext.Result`, but in this case `response.Filter`).

The MVC framework takes care of executing the action. That is done at a later point in the request lifecycle than when it is set.

To answer the question

> Why is the author using OnActionExecuting instead of OnActionExected?

`OnActionExecuted` fires *after* the action is completed. Setting a filter at that point is too late in the request lifecycle for it to have any effect.

Comment: i think we can minify html after action execution because we need html and minify it before sending it to client. so why need to hook before action execute because html is generated from action method. so i believe we should get html after action execution from OnActionExecuted filter.......am i right?

Comment: However you look at it, it is not the filter's job to execute the action. It is the filters job to determine whether to take action, and set a handler if there is some action to take. I suspect if you set the `Filter` property after the action has executed it will have no effect because the action is what uses the filter. Refer to the [MVC lifecycle documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application).